# Conditional Compilation in Xamrine.forms for iOS and Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I had created Xamarin project. Which had Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS projects.
Below are the steps i performed.
1) Added Define Symbols for **ANDROID**;**IOS** in compiler.

[image]

2) Added conditional coding in  content page.

[image]

3) It is not able to find Specific coding for Android where there are libraries only addd in Android.
    FM.LiveSwitch.Android 1.8.1.24030 is not compatible with netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0). Package FM.LiveSwitch.Android 1.8.1.24030 supports: monoandroid70 (MonoAndroid,Version=v7.0)

Is there any way i can add that in Xamrine.forms ?

Comment: The short answer is "no", you would need to use a "Shared Projects (also sometimes called Shared Asset Projects)" based project : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/cross-platform/app-fundamentals/shared-projects?tabs=macos

Comment: conditional compilation only works with shared projects, which have been deprecated in favor of .NET Standard

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But how can i connect Shared project with Xamarin.forms, Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS

Comment: For a Shared Project to be useful, it needs to be referenced by at least one build-able project (such as an iOS or Android application or library, or a PCL project).Adding a reference to a Shared Project is done the same way as referencing a regular Library project.